# KnockoutJS observableArray to update when inner observable is changed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to know how to trigger the update for an `observableArray` when an `observable` is changed inside the `observableArray`.

I have an `observableArray` that represents a binary tree. I'm using a storage mapping function to get and set the values in the array so it has to be balance even thought it might only contain an empty `observable`. E.g. nodes()[9] maybe null but when that node is updated I would call `nodes()[9](set new value)` and need to trigger the `observableArray` to update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up using .replace() on the observableArray

Answer (score 3):

Managed to look through the code and find observableArray.replace ()

RELATED: [How to replace a given index element in knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425409/how-to-replace-a-given-index-elemet-in-knocountjs)

Comment: replace is ideal here. another option tho is to use splice to pull the item out and then to push the replacement item in. but again, replace is a better option.

Comment: Yes but if I used splice how would I insert it back into the correct position?

Comment: splice can add, remove or add and remove elements from arbitrary positions. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice. for example `array.splice(3, 1, 'hello')` implements "replace" in pure javascript. KO gives you extra convenience methods on observableArrays. another example only adding elements ad a given position is `array.splice(3, 0, 'hello', 'world')`.

Comment: @saurus Thanks I can't believe I didn't even think to do that! but replaced worked fine in my case because the element was already there.

Comment: Yep, as I said, splice can remove at a position or insert at a position. But that's 2 lines of code ... and for what you are doing, replace works best.