# Updating an observableArray does not update UI

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using the containerless flow control in ko 2.0. When I update an item in my observableArray it is not updating the UI. I am updating the array like this:

```
this.editFormHost = function (formHost) {
    ...
    formHost.HostName = newHostName;
    this.formHosts[index] = formHost;
}
```

I am thinking it doesn't update because updating the array by index does not call anything in ko. From looking at [the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) it looks like there are no methods to update an object which will in turn update the UI. Or is there?

Comment: A bit difficult to help without seeing your viewmodel, and understanding what you are trying to do. As a start point, have you seen this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774943/knockoutjs-observablearray-to-update-when-inner-observable-is-changed and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425409/how-to-replace-a-given-index-element-in-knockoutjs ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a a fiddle that demonstrates how to replace an item in an observableArray and have its changes notify the UI.

http://jsfiddle.net/johnpapa/ckMJE/

The key here is the replace function on the observableArray. You could also use splice.

... Notice the use of "replace" below ...

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.self = this;
    self.index = ko.observable(0); // default
    self.newColor = ko.observable("purple"); // default
    self.colors = ko.observableArray([{
        color: 'red'},
    {
        color: 'blue'},
    {
        color: 'yellow'}]);
    self.replaceIt = function() {
        self.colors.replace(self.colors()[self.index()], {
            color: self.newColor()
        });
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: someone should add that replace method to the documentation. worked great, thanks!

Comment: good point. i've added it to my Knockout course because i get asked about it a lot.