# Knockout Observable collection's property value not updating in UI

Tags: knockout.js, observablecollection

```
  vm.SortDxCodeUp = function (currentitem, previousItem, dxCodesObservable,codeType) {

        var currentDxCode = currentitem;
        var previousDxCode = previousItem;

        if (currentDxCode.Index > 0)
        {
           var tempCurrentSortOrder = currentDxCode.SortOrder;
           var tempPreviousSortOrder = previousDxCode.SortOrder;

           dxCodesObservable()[currentitem.Index - 1] = currentDxCode;
           dxCodesObservable()[currentitem.Index] = previousDxCode;

           dxCodesObservable()[currentitem.Index - 1].SortOrder = tempPreviousSortOrder;
           dxCodesObservable()[currentitem.Index].SortOrder = tempCurrentSortOrder;

           dxCodesObservable.valueHasMutated();
        }
 };
```

I am modifying an observable array which is dxCodesObservable in above code. SortOrder is a property in that array. I am modifying its value, but the value does not get reflected in the UI. I have checked that the array does contain the right values for the property.
Is this happening because SortOrder property is not an observable inside the collection ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating an observableArray does not update UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861106/updating-an-observablearray-does-not-update-ui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this happening because SortOrder property is not an observable
>   inside the collection?

Yes that is exactly why.