# Modifying a knockout.js model from outside of it

Tags: knockout.js

I have a simple model for keeping my folders:

```
var FolderModel = {
    folders: ko.observableArray([
        {id:'Global', uid: 'Global', name: 'Global', count:0}, 
        {id:'New', uid: 'New', name: 'New', count:0}, 
        {id:'Important', uid: 'Important', name: 'Important', count:0} 
    ]);
```

This model is binded to:

```
<ul class="folder-tree" data-bind="foreach: FolderModel.folders">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>
        <span class="count" data-bind="text: $data.count"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So the initial view will be something like this:

- Global (0)
- New (0)
- Important (0)

Then I'm doing some request polling in another script: waiting for the counts to change and update the model. Yet, nothing I've done worked. I have tried:

```
var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(FolderModel.folders(), function (item) {
    return c == item.uid;
});

if (match) {
    match.count = counts[c];
}
```

c - here is the uid of the folder. So, I use arrayFirst, get the item in the observable array and update it.

The next thing I tried:

```
    $.each(FolderModel.folders(), function (index, folder) {
        var newFolder = FolderModel.folders()[index];
        newFolder.count = counts[folder.uid];
        FolderModel.folders.replace(FolderModel.folders()[index], newFolder);
    });
```

This also brought me nowhere and also looks quite silly, but I found this at another SO issue [How to replace a given index element in knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425409/how-to-replace-a-given-index-element-in-knockoutjs)

What am I doing wrong and what didn't I get in the knockout.js? I was thinking that whener the observable arrays element gets modified and if it is data-binded to something, that something will be modified as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a folder to be a view model for Knockout to catch the changes or use `observableArray` methods to change the array:

```
var Folder = function (id, uid, name, count) {
    // things that don't change don't need observables
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.uid = ko.observable(uid);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.count = ko.observable(count);
};

var FolderModel = {
    folders: ko.observableArray([
        {id:'Global', uid: 'Global', name: 'Global', count:0}, 
        {id:'New', uid: 'New', name: 'New', count:0}, 
        {id:'Important', uid: 'Important', name: 'Important', count:0} 
    ])
};

var FolderModelNew = {
    folders: ko.observableArray([
        new Folder('Global', 'Global', 'Global', 0),
        new Folder('New', 'New', 'New', 0),
        new Folder('Important', 'Important', 'Important', 0)
    ])
};

var vm = {
    folderModel: FolderModel,
    folderModelNew: FolderModelNew
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

vm.folderModel.folders()[1].name = '111'; // nothing
vm.folderModel.folders.splice(0, 1, {id:'Global', uid: 'Global', name: '000', count:0}); // updated
vm.folderModelNew.folders()[1].name('111'); // updated
​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sgc5J/

Answer (score 2):

The **ko.observableArray only tracks if items are added or deleted from the collection.** But if you change an item inside the observable array the UI won't updated automatically.

[From the documentation:](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)

> Key point: An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array,
>   not the state of those objects

So you need to make the `count` properties inside the `folders` collection observable

```
var FolderModel = {
    folders: ko.observableArray([
        {id:'Global', uid: 'Global', name: 'Global', count: ko.observable(0) }, 
        {id:'New', uid: 'New', name: 'New', count: ko.observable(0) }, 
        {id:'Important', uid: 'Important', name: 'Important', count: ko.observable(0) } 
    ]);
```

Eventually if you need to update all the properties you have to make all of them observable. There is a plugin for KO called [KO mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) which can help you with that.

And your update code should look like this:

```
var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(FolderModel.folders(), function (item) {
    return c == item.uid;
});

if (match) {
    match.count(counts[c]); // because count is now observable
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwM5M/) where you play with it.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding you correctly - you cannot update a property of an element in a `ko.observableArray` and trigger updates to the array.  You need to do this:

```
folders: ko.observableArray([
    { id: ko.observable('Global'), uid: ko.observable('Global'), name: ko.observable('Global'), count: ko.observable(0)}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you better to use [subscriber in knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) if you want to get changing event from another script